# Using gdb to decode hex data to struct

Tags: gdb

I have a hex stream of hex data that is printed like

0x3a45 0x1234 0x0352 (in real far longer)

I know that it is content in a struct. Is there a way in gdb to map this on the struct? Gdb seems only to accept single values for doing this.

Like:

(gdb) print (myStruct) 0x3a45 0x1234 0x0352

$1 = { a = 3a, b = 45, f = 0x1234, c = 03, e = 52}

In this case it's very simple but there is complex struct and the hex string is far larger.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple viable ways to do this in gdb.

The simplest way is to write the data into the inferior's memory somehow.  It might look something like:

```
(gdb) set $mem = malloc(50)   # number of bytes
(gdb) set $mem[0] = 0x72
(gdb) set $mem[1] = 0xff
# etc - you can find faster ways to do this
(gdb) print *(struct whatever *) $mem
```

Filling the memory is a pain, but this can be scripted.  For example you can write a little shell script to convert the raw bytes into a sequence of `set` commands and then `source` it.  Or you can just write a new gdb command in Python that automates it all.

gdb also has an extension to let one create an array on the command line, and do a kind of "reinterpret cast" on it.  I found this method a bit less handy, because I could only make the array feature create arrays of `int`, not `char`.  But anyhow, consider this little program:

```
struct x {
  int a;
  long b;
};

int main() {
  struct x x = { 23, 97 };
  return 0;
}
```

I start gdb and stop on the `return`, then examine the memory:

```
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$1 = 4
(gdb) p sizeof(x)
$2 = 16
(gdb) x/4xw &x
0x7fffffffe240: 0x00000017  0x00007fff  0x00000061  0x00000000
```

(That second word is garbage because it is in the struct padding...)

Now we can recreate `x` by hand from the raw data:

```
(gdb) print {struct x}{0x17, 0x7fff, 0x61, 0}
$3 = {
  a = 23, 
  b = 97
}
```

This expression uses two extensions to C expressions that gdb provides.  First, `{0x17, 0x7fff...}` is a way to write an array.  Second, `{struct x}` is a kind of "reinterpret cast" - it reinterprets the raw bytes of the value as named type.