# How to convert hex data to a data structure in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, coredump

I usually analyzing some hex dump from crash log, this hex dump belong to some very complicate data structure.

So I wander if gdb has some convenient command to translate the hexdump to data structure.

For example, I got some the hexdump `0xAAABBCCDDEEFF`, is there a way to convert it back to the data structure?

for example:

```
p ((struct very_complcate_structure)(0xAABBCCDDEEFF)).u.flag.a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gdb to decode hex data to struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653514/using-gdb-to-decode-hex-data-to-struct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I got some the hexdump 0xAAABBCCDDEEFF

The trick is to get these values into memory of a running process. It may be useful to write a tiny helper program for this.

For example, suppose that you have a hex dump of a packet, and the remote server printed that packet out, then crashed. (The usual way to debug this is to make remote server dump `core`, and then debug that `core` -- this will allow you to debug many more problems than what is possible to debug using your "logging" approach, but I digress).

So we write a helper program like this (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "packet.h"   // "complicated" packet structure defined here.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct packet pkt;
  static const int num_ints = ((sizeof(pkt) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1)) / sizeof(int);

  for (int j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
    memset(&pkt, 0, sizeof(pkt));  // start in clean state

    // chop input string into 8-char chunks
    std::string s = argv[j];
    for (int k = 0; k < num_ints && k < (s.size() / 8) + 1 ; k++) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::hex << s.substr(8 * k, 8);

      unsigned int x;
      ss >> x;
      ((unsigned int *)&pkt)[k] = x;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;  // break here.
  }
}
```

Now compile this program with `g++ -g helper.cc -o helper`, run it with

```
gdb -q ./helper AAABBCCDDEEFF....
```

Set breakpoint on line 24 (the "break here" line), and use `print pkt` to examine the decoded packet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but in my case, the debug info has already build-in, the problem is  hex data comes from remote server which hash already crashed and dump these hex values.

I have to analyze the hex values to get the useful information, the data structure is very very big, this is why I hope gdb can help.

Comment: Yes, this is a brilliant idea. And I found another approach is to use the gdb python extension . Anyway, I love your idea because I hate python and  prefer writing some C code.